# MySQL Árabe retorna?

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Estou com o seguinte problema: 
No meu código PHP estou fazendo um `select` em uma tabela que contem informações em árabe `اختبار`. Porem no PHP esta retornando `?????`.

Estou usando o Php 5.2.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez seja necessário definir o *charset*, use a função [`mysqli_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.set-charset.php).

Veja um exemplo (retirado da documentação):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

printf("Initial character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: deu certo utilizei o mysql_set_charset. Obrigado.